# How can I find the macOS version codename?

Tags: macos

I want to find the codename of my version of OS X / macOS.

E.g. Lion, Leopard, Mavericks, etc.

If I click the Apple symbol, then "About This Mac", I only get the version number.

Where can I find the Big Cat or California Location marketing codename?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The version number is the correct thing to report when you have issues. You should also include the subversion.

The marketing names are from [macOS - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS#Release_history) article, up to and including macOS Monterey.

| **Version** | **Codename** |
| --- | --- |
| Rhapsody Developer Release | Grail1Z4 / Titan1U |
| Mac OS X Server 1.0 | Hera |
| Mac OS X Developer Preview |  |
| Public Beta | Kodiak |
| Mac OS X 10.0 | Cheetah |
| Mac OS X 10.1 | Puma |
| Mac OS X 10.2 | Jaguar |
| Mac OS X 10.3 | Panther |
| Mac OS X 10.4 | Tiger |
| Mac OS X 10.5 | Leopard |
| Mac OS X 10.6 | Snow Leopard |
| Mac OS X 10.7 | Lion |
| OS X 10.8 | Mountain Lion |
| OS X 10.9 | Mavericks |
| OS X 10.10 | Yosemite |
| OS X 10.11 | El Capitan |
| macOS 10.12 | Sierra |
| macOS 10.13 | High Sierra |
| macOS 10.14 | Mojave |
| macOS 10.15 | Catalina |
| macOS 11 | Big Sur |
| macOS 12 | Monterey |
| macOS 13 | Ventura |
| macOS 14 | Sonoma |

Answer (score 7):

As of OS X 10.10 Yosemite, the name of the OS *is* listed in About This Mac.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Click on the black Apple icon in the leftmost upper corner of your display when in Finder.
Your Operating System is listed under the bold-faced "OS X"

Note:  If you click on the icon reading "More Info" you will get **all** of the hardware info related to your Mac.

Comment: The OP is doing what you suggest. The About This Mac screen only shows the OS X version number, not its name.